# likelihood field of map

Tags: navigation, mapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'd like to ask about a convert of a map data.

Amcl package uses map.pgm with map.yaml.
However, map.png which is gained by slam_gmapping
has solid edges to represent obstacles(walls, tables and so on).

**When and where a map data is converted to a likelihood field ?**

(If possible, could you show me the correspond part of source codes?)
And which parameter is used to determine the likelihood field's standard deviation?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49807/likelihood-field-of-map/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, gmapping maintains occupancy values internally. However, the ROS wrapper thresholds them into binary free/occupied values.

Take a look at this file:

[slam_gmapping.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/gmapping/html/slam__gmapping_8cpp_source.html)

Starting at line 625:

```
for(int x=0; x < smap.getMapSizeX(); x++)
{
  for(int y=0; y < smap.getMapSizeY(); y++)
  {
    GMapping::IntPoint p(x, y);
    double occ=smap.cell(p);
    assert(occ <= 1.0);
    if(occ < 0)
      map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = -1;
    else if(occ > occ_thresh_)
    {
      //map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = (int)round(occ*100.0);
      map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = 100;
    }
    else
      map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = 0;
  }
}
```

The default value for `occ_thresh_` is 0.25. It appears that if you want the occupancy values, you can simply revert the line which was commented out, and change the code to:

```
map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = (int)round(occ*100.0);
//map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = 100;
```

I have created a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5589) here.

**EDIT**: response to comment

I'm not sure whether amcl currently assumes binary values or not.

With laser sensors, you typically reach saturation probabilities (0 or 1) pretty fast, since lasers have a small uncertainty spread. My intuition is that since the nav stack is mainly developed for laser-equipped ground robots, the binary value is a good approximation.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2012-12-06**:
Thank you for your kind answer and creating the ticket !!
After I change the line, I need to modify amcl package to use likelihood field which doesn't have binary values but 0～255 values don't I ?
Why do you think nav stack use binary values even though it's less robust ?

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2012-12-09**:
Thank you for your response.I'd like to be sure whether amcl assumes binary or not. Would you mind if I ask the question in an additional question form which includes url info of this form?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-12-09**:
sure, sounds like a good idea

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2012-12-10**:
Thanks a lot. I posted new question here.(http://answers.ros.org/question/50134/can-amcl-pack-use-a-map-data-as-a-likelihood-field/)